# Q about isomorphic Javascript - why doesn't it double up on the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript, server-side-rendering

Ok, this question may reveal a misunderstanding of the basics of the classic HTML/javascript combo, but here goes...

Say I have a (relatively) simple app that utilises the concept of isomorphic Javascript, rendered first on the server side and then by the browser. For instance, this one:

https://github.com/jesstelford/react-isomorphic-boilerplate

The app first renders the following server side (via res.send()):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">
  <body>
    <div id="content">{{{content}}}</div>
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The content moustaches features some React code.

The browser then picks up the browserified bundle in the script tag (which has exactly the same React code in it). React apparently sees that there is no change in state and does not therefore re-render the DOM. The page is loaded quickly and the user will see no change (no flash).

Here is my question, though: why does the rendered DOM element only appear once?

Given that it is represented twice in the above HTML (in the div line and the script line), I would have thought you would see it twice. Instead, the browser's version simply replaces the server-rendered version. This is clearly a very useful effect, but I'd appreciate it if someone could explain to me why things work this way.

Thank you

Comment: Because when you gave the App it's mount point you specified the div with id `content` and there's only one of that div...

Comment: Thanks. So using React.render() with a target mount point (as the bundle in this example does) will always replace whatever's already in there rather than augment it?

Comment: Yes, all that div is belong to react now.

Comment: In Javascript, q or Q mean some kind of Promise.